# how I can solve a problem with cplex import in python

Tags: python, cplex

I am trying to install cplex for python 2.7.9. I downloaded IBM ILOG CPLEX Studio 12.6.1 Academic Version and I have installed it using command line. The return was:

```
===============================================================================
Instalação concluída
--------------------

O IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 20.1.0 foi instalado com sucesso no:

   /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201
```

Additionally I executed the code:

```
python /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/python/setup.py install
```

and the return was

```
...
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/lp/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/modeler.py to modeler.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/function.py to function.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/catalog.py to catalog.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/config.py to config.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/parameters.py to parameters.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cp/utils.py to utils.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/cli.py to cli.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex-2.18.200.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docplex-2.18.200.egg-info
** The documentation can be found here: https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc
** The examples can be found here: https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples
```

Now I need to import cplex in a code made using python, I'm using:

```
import cplex
```

But I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cplex
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .aborter import Aborter
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/aborter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._internal import _procedural as _proc
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/_internal/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _aux_functions
ImportError: cannot import name _aux_functions
```

Someone knows how I can resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The import statement says that you are using `python 3.7`

Comment: Yes. In the folder /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/ I have only 3.7 and 3.8 python version. There is some problem?

Comment: *I am trying to install cplex for python 2.7.9*

Comment: Now I run the code using python3, but I sill have an error:

Comment: Why would you install it for a different (and incompatible) python version and expect it to run?

Comment: root@VMHenrique:~# python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cplex
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .aborter import Aborter
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/aborter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._internal import _procedural as _proc
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/_internal/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>

Comment: File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/_internal/_list_array_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex as CPX
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/_internal/_pycplex.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex_platform
  File "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/cplex/_internal/_pycplex_platform.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise Exception(ERROR_STRING)
Exception: CPLEX 20.1.0.0 is not compatible with this version of Python.

Comment: this is the version that I have to download. can I choose a different version of cplex to use a different version of python?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have installed a version of Cplex that only supports v3.7 and 3.8 to Python 2.7. I think you either need to reinstall Cplex to your Python 3 packages and see if it works correctly, or you need to install an earlier version of Cplex (say 12.8) that supports Python 2.7.

You are probably having issues because you've installed an incompatible version to the wrong library.  So, if you want Python 2 - try and earlier Cplex version that is compatible. If you want Cplex 20, try redoing the installation using Python 3 so that the packages end up in the right place.